# How to prevent Webpack process to remove type="text" from input markup

Tags: html, webpack

Here's the interesting excerpt of my Webpack configuration:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'ng-annotate!babel?presets[]=es2015'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!sass")
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]?[hash]"
            },
            {
                test: /\.tpl\.html$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "html-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I run `webpack -p`, I complain about removed `type="text"` from some HTML inputs.

I have some CSS styling some components regarding presence of `type="text"`.

Is there a way to prevent Webpack's production process (uglifying?) to remove this HTML attribute?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/752

Answer (score 3):

For webpack 5, try to disable `removeRedundantAttributes` for HtmlWebpackPlugin's minifier:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: `./src/index.html`,
  filename: `index.html`,
  minify: {
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    keepClosingSlash: true,
    removeComments: true,
    removeRedundantAttributes: false, // do not remove type="text"
    removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
    useShortDoctype: true
  }
});
```

docs: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#minification

Answer (score 0):

**minify: false** should do the trick.
For me removeRedundantAttributes didnt work.